# Remove all but a specific row from a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove all rows apart from the row with id 'row0' from a table:

```
<table class="mytable">
    <tr id="row0" class="myrow">
        <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="myrow">
        <td>bbb</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="myrow">
        <td>ccc</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But the following JQuery code removes ALL rows:

```
$('.mytable').children().not('#row0').remove();
```

Could someone explain why this happens? I would think that the child with id 'row0' would be excluded, but obviously that's not the case.

I have found another way to do this but still curious why the above method doesn't work:

```
$('.mytable').find('tr:not(#row0)').remove();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the children of a `table` element are `thead`, `tfoot` or `tbody` elements. [A `tbody` element is always created in the generated DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/table.tBodies), even if it is not explicitly written in the HTML code.

You can also do:

```
$('.mytable tr').not('#row0').remove();
```

or

```
$('#row0').siblings().remove();
```

Comment: i like the siblings() method :)